# Printing single result from db2 query in php

Tags: php, sql, db2

I'm running a query on db2 in a php script, which is running successfully but I can't get it to echo the actual ID of the record I've selected. It does echo my success statement showing it ran successfully  but I need the actual `sessionid` for comparison in another query.

Here I'm selecting the record, executing the query and checking for execution, but I'm also trying to use fetch_row and result to return the single selected ID:

```
$latest_result = "SELECT MAX(SESSIONID) as SESSIONID FROM session";
$prepareSessionMax = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $latest_result);
$executeSessionMax = odbc_execute($prepareSessionMax);

while(odbc_fetch_row($executeSessionMax)){
  $maxResult = odbc_result($executeSessionMax, "SESSIONID");
  echo $maxResult;
}
```

How can I return the sessionID into a variable properly from db2?

Comment: That's what I thought, but my echo statement doesn't show anything. It goes through the rest of the script and I have an if/else on the execution which prints that it did in fact execute but I need to see the ID in my terminal and it doesn't show

Comment: _but I need the actual sessionid for comparison in another query_ Well you have it in `$maxResult` so whars the problem.

Comment: I don't know that I do though, I'm trying to debug by printing $maxResult and it's not printing which means I don't have it

Comment: _Silly suggestion, as I dont know DB2_ Try `SELECT MAX(SESSIONID) as maxId FROM session` maybe it has issues with using the actual column name as an alias

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work but that is a good suggestion because it can be picky sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong parameter to the `odbc_fetch_row()` as `$executeSessionMax` is either a True or False depending on successful execution.

```
$latest_result = "SELECT MAX(SESSIONID) as SESSIONID FROM session";
$prepareSessionMax = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $latest_result);
$executeSessionMax = odbc_execute($prepareSessionMax);

while(odbc_fetch_row($prepareSessionMax )){
//  correction here  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  $maxResult = odbc_result($executeSessionMax, "SESSIONID");
  echo $maxResult;
}
```

You could recode as this specially as a MAX() will only ever return one row so the while loop is not needed either.

```
$latest_result = "SELECT MAX(SESSIONID) as SESSIONID FROM session";
$prepareSessionMax = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $latest_result);
if (odbc_execute($prepareSessionMax)) {

    odbc_fetch_row($prepareSessionMax );
    $maxResult = odbc_result($executeSessionMax, "SESSIONID");
    echo $maxResult;
    // if echo gets lost try writing to a file
    error_log("maxResult = $maxResult", 3, "my-errors.log");

} else {
    // something went wrong in the execute
}
```

You could also try

```
$latest_result = "SELECT MAX(SESSIONID) as SESSIONID FROM session";
$result = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $latest_result);
$rows = odbc_fetch_object($result); 
echo $row->SESSIONID;
$maxResult = $row->SESSIONID;
```

Comment: Well I do like the refactor you made and it still does in fact execute without error, but still doesn't echo the ID of pass it into my next query for some reason. I accepted it though because this is cleaner and a more appropriate approach. I'll just have to keep playing with the echo statement

Comment: Maybe I should be using fetch_object instead of row?

Comment: Sometimes echo's get lost depending on what you are doing. If you are throwing a different page later in the code, then the echo will get lost.

Comment: See edited answer, try writing the echo to a file instead of an echo

Comment: Ah good thought. Ok that wrote to the txt file with maxResult =  and it's blank

Comment: Ooohh Pooooo :)

Comment: so it is executing and the query itself works directly in the IDE but I think something isn't returning properly from the fetch_row

Comment: Another suggestion using `odbc_exec()` as your query does not actually need preparing as it has not parameters

Comment: ha, your last edit worked perfectly. I appreciate it!

Comment: YIppeee. And me having never used the odbc api before :)